# ubuntu 14 corrupt desktop

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, panel

I've done quite a bit of poking around and trying to solve my problem.  Usually I can manage but nothing seems to be working.

My wife's PC is running Ubuntu 14.  Her desktop has become corrupt.  The task bar and launcher(vertical row of icons at left) have disappeared.
programs will launch from icons on desktop but none of the programs have menus available. Have to exit with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>.

Apparently this has happened before as I left myself a note to

```
cp /usr/share/lxpanel/profile/Lubuntu/panels/panel ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels
```

this did not work this time .
I tried deleting the file  panel, no luck
I tried removing and reinstalling gnome no luck
I tried installing unity-tweak-tool and resetting - no luck
If I log in as guest there is a perfect desktop.

Comment: Run these: `cp /usr/share/lxpanel/profile/Lubuntu/panels/panel ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels; 
lxpanelctl restart`. You were trying to copy file from wrong location.

Comment: Yes I typed it incorrectly above but I did have the correct path when I tried it (many times) with no luck.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try this" `rm -r ~/.config/lxpanel; lxpanelctl restart`

Comment: tried your first suggestion again and get no such directory error.   when checked there is no lxpanel directory in /.config

Comment: second sugestion  returns cant connect to display: (null)

Comment: could I copy the panel file from the guest account to my wifes?

Comment: Yeah. You can give it a try. Do you have any other drive like HDD partition/USB flash storage? If yes, do copy file while in guest mode to that storage and relogin and copy file to specified folders.

Comment: should I create the ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels directory?

Comment: Yeah. If doesn't exist. You might need sudo privileges.

Comment: arggg. when logged in as guest the there is no panel file in the panels dir

Comment: You might like add a new user and check if the file is available there.

Comment: added new user added to sudo.  got a nice new desktop for that user but cant find the panel file and wifes desktop still not working properly.  It says not to use comments for discussion should we talk somewhere else?  Is there another approach to this problem?